# Error in converting json string as a json objects

Tags: flutter

I am using `Completer` to listen `onstatechanged` and everything is working fine i get a json response but what i really want to do is changing the json string to json object using model class by calling `MediaData.fromJson(data)`.. but i always get error...

Here is what i had tried so far

```
class mainController{
  Future<MediaData> getdata() async{
    final completer = Completer<MediaData>();

    final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.launch('https://www.instagram.com/picsart/?__a=1', hidden: true, userAgent: kAndroidUserAgent,);


    flutterWebViewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((viewState) async {
      if (viewState.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
        final data = await flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.documentElement.outerText");

       
        completer.complete(MediaData.fromJson(json.decode(data)));


        flutterWebViewPlugin.close();
      }
    });

    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

Error -

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
E/flutter (20186): #0      mainController.getdata.<anonymous closure> (package:igsavers/controller/mainController.dart:20:52)
E/flutter (20186): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20186):
```

I posted the picture of the error in compiler which i get  - [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9JhU.png)

-- Here is my model [MediaData](https://pastiebin.com/606071891a25a) rawcode...

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to be in the line 20
[image]

Instead of using `MediaData.fromJson(json.decode(data))`, try `MediaData.fromJson(data)`.

The `json.decode` must receive an `String`, but data is currently a `Map<String, dynamic>`. Then, the usage of this functions is unnecessary.

Comment: i figured out that while ago ... but still getting error in compiler ... please see the error screenshot

Comment: I edited the answer based on your new edited question. Please check it out again.

Comment: After removing json decode i get errorr in my android studio - ```The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'```

Comment: What is the type of `data`?

Comment: the type of data is string

Comment: Can you show the value of `data`, please?

Comment: Yup sure i am sending you value of data

Comment: final data value ```"{\"logging_page_id\":\"profilePage_1936047006\",\"show_suggested_profiles\":false,\"show_follow_dialog\":false,\"graphql\":{\"user\":{\"biography\":\"Is PicsArt your go-to photo & video editing app? Tag your remixes #heypicsart here on Insta for a chance to be featured on our page! #makeawesome \\ud83d\\ude0d\\ud83d\\udd25\",```

Comment: I removed many string response bcz stackoverflow don't allow to write that much text

Comment: Can you use divide your line 20 into many lines?
```
final map = json.decode(data) as Map<String, dynamic>;
final mediaData = MediaData.fromMap(map);
completer.compleate(mediaData);
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error ```Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter (28356): #0      mainController.getdata.<anonymous closure> (package:igsavers/controller/mainController.dart:21:39)
E/flutter (28356): <asynchronous suspension>```